# UITextView scroll bug iOS9 xcode 7.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, xcode7

I have a simple UITextView that occupies all the screen.
When the text length is bigger than the Textview height, it automatically scrolls to the bottom (see image).

I have already tried

```
self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
```

and

`self.textView.scrollsToTop = true`

and other things without any result.

I'm using iOS 9 with the latest swift and Xcode 7.1.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```

but I still don't understand why it didn't work.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem, as right now i am not able to test the code, will you tell me the above code will solve this problem or not.

Comment: the code in my answer solved the problem in my case.

Comment: This fixes it, but there is a jump as it is only laid out when the view has appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You also try

```
 self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location:0, length:0))
```